# Did you forget to pass the collection object for will_paginate? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

On Rails, I get the error "...,Did you forget to pass the collection object for will_paginate?" I am using the will_paginate gem along with mailboxer

view/conversations

```
<p><%= link_to 'Start conversation', new_message_path, class: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary' %></p>

<ul class="list-group">
  <%= render partial: 'conversations/conversation', collection: @conversations %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

controller/conversations

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_member!
  #before_action :get_mailbox
  before_action :get_conversation, except: [:index]

  def show
  end

  private

  def get_conversation
    @conversation ||= @mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
 # @conversations = Conversation.paginate(page: params[:page]) # paginated

       @conversations = Conversation.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)    

    end

end
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and their linked pages. Your didn't ask a question nor do you show an error or how to run your code. Please review the help for editing and formatting your text and make it so it's readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<%= will_paginate @conversations %>
Check this you need to pass the variable, you want to paginate.